# How can I use openfiles.exe to disconnect files below a directory

Tags: windows, deployment, cmd, msbuild

I want to utilise the Microsoft windows command Openfiles in an MsBuild task to disconnect users from DLLs before deploying.

[Openfiles.exe /disconnect](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490961.aspx)

The wildcard **(*)** can be used to disconnect all open files on the specified computer.

I would like to only disconnect locked files BELOW a specific target directory.

However, this isn't explained in the help guide.

Can this be done?

Comment: Explain what do you mean "**BELOW a specific target directory**"? Do you want to do that using msbuild project file?

Comment: Really? Erm ... all files in directories below a target directory. \**\*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with msbuild project, you can achive this using [MSBuild Batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <File Include="$(TargetDir)**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Disconnect">
    <Exec Command="openfiles /disconnect &quot;%(File.FullPath)&quot;" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This batching will take every file in the folder $(TargetDir) and its subfolers, and for each file will execute the command.

Comment: Thanks @stukselbak. Looks good. I'll give it a try and click the tick when I get it working.